# Example of free downloadable SVG font with complex curves

Tags: fonts, svg, glyphs

I am trying to learn about SVG curves and how font glyphs are built. Specifically how you *taper* complex curves. I'm wondering if it's the stroke that is tapered or it is a fill. I'm wondering too how the structure of the SVG markup is to allow for animating a font. Wondering if one could link to a good, possibly animatable ("stroke" animation, even though what may be stroke may actually be a fill of some sort), svg glyph or font.

Searching for free, downloadable SVG fonts leads to a lot of pinterest and dribbble posts without content, or paid-only content.

Comment: check this question https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/118982/algorithm-for-drawing-calligraphy-brush-strokes-in-svg

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Seems like you might want to look into https://thenounproject.com/term/open-source/ as a first step.